# how to enable or disable radio button based on checkbox in wix toolset installer

Tags: windows, wix, installation

I have created wix installer on which I have added checkbox and corresponding radio button. If check box is unchecked then corresponding radio button should get disabled. user have option to install only if checkbox is checked. Image is attached for reference.

[image: Dialog with radio button and Checkbox]

Comment: This question isn't a debugging question. It's asking "how to". Thus, closing it as lacking a [MCVE] is inappropriate. The "no MCVE" close reason only applies to debugging questions. While it would be a better question with some code indicating how they created their current layout, that's not actually a required element for this type of question and this question can be (and has been) answered without it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bob Arnson on the wix-users forums](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/disabling-a-single-RadioButton-td694368.html), there is apparently no way to disable one radio button within a button group:

> MSI doesn't support that. In MSI terms, the radio button group is the 
>   control and the radio buttons are non-control children. It's annoying 
>   and not intuitive but that's how MSI works at the moment.

However, even if you can't enable or disable (hide or show) a single button in a button group, you can do that to the entire button group. For example:

```
<Control Id="InstallationTypeRadioButton" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="INSTALLTYPE" X="135" Y="150" Width="220" Height="38">
  <RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALLTYPE">
    <RadioButton Value="FULL" Text="Sandalone" X="0" Y="0" Width="220" Height="20" />
    <RadioButton Value="DISTRIBUTED" Text="Distributed" X="0" Y="20" Width="220" Height="20" />
  </RadioButtonGroup>
</Control>

<Control Id="InstallationDistributedTypeRadioButton" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="DISTRIBUTEDTYPE" X="135" Y="188" Width="220" Height="40">
  <RadioButtonGroup Property="DISTRIBUTEDTYPE">
    <RadioButton Value="MASTER" Text="Master" X="15" Y="0" Width="220" Height="20" />
    <RadioButton Value="SLAVE" Text="Slave" X="15" Y="20" Width="220" Height="20" />
  </RadioButtonGroup>
  <Condition Action="show"> <![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE="DISTRIBUTED"]]> </Condition>
  <Condition Action="hide"> <![CDATA[INSTALLTYPE<>"DISTRIBUTED"]]> </Condition>
</Control>
```

This piece of code allows you to show or hide a radio button group depending on a selection from another button group.

The result would look like the following:

[image: the visual example for this code]